# Update part of an object

Tags: go

I wish to have a map in the format of:

```
mapName[someIntegerID].Title.EN_US

mapName[someIntegerID].Title.ZH_HK

mapName[someIntegerID].Title.ZH_CN

mapName[someIntegerID].Content.EN_US

mapName[someIntegerID].Content.ZH_HK

mapName[someIntegerID].Content.ZH_CN
```

Actually is the above making sense? Anyway, I tried the code below. The api json response format is perfect, however, I noticed during the forloop, zh_HK will override that of en_US, as well as zh_CN will override zh_HK and en_US, resulting on right zh_CN value but empty en_US and zh_HK values.

Can experts give me some suggestion how I can achieve it?

```
type Hello struct {
    Title   Locale `json:"title"`
    Content Locale `json:"content"`
}

type Locale struct {
    EN_US string `json:"en-US"`
    ZH_HK string `json:"zh-HK"`
    ZH_CN string `json:"zh-CN"`
}


someMap := map[int]Hello{}
for _, recordTranslations := range recordsTranslations {
    if _, has := someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID]; !has {
        someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID] = Hello{}
    }

    if recordTranslations.Locale == "en-US" {
        someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID] = Hello{
            Title: Locale{
                EN_US: recordTranslations.Title,
            },
            Content: Locale{
                EN_US: recordTranslations.Content,
            },
        }
    } else if recordTranslations.Locale == "zh-HK" {
        someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID] = Hello{
            Title: Locale{
                ZH_HK: recordTranslations.Title,
            },
            Content: Locale{
                ZH_HK: recordTranslations.Content,
            },
        }

    } else if recordTranslations.Locale == "zh-CN" {
        someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID] = Hello{
            Title: Locale{
                ZH_CN: recordTranslations.Title,
            },
            Content: Locale{
                ZH_CN: recordTranslations.Content,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello object  getting overridden  because you are creating a new hello object everytime if you don't want to override just update the object .

```
type Hello struct {
Title   Locale `json:"title"`
Content Locale `json:"content"
}
type Locale struct {
EN_US string `json:"en-US"`
ZH_HK string `json:"zh-HK"`
ZH_CN string `json:"zh-CN"`
}
someMap := map[int]Hello{}
for _, recordTranslations := range recordsTranslations {
    if _, has := someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID]; !has {
        someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID] = Hello{}
}

if recordTranslations.Locale == "en-US" {
    someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID].Title.EN_US = recordTranslations.Title
        someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID].Content.EN_US = recordTranslations.Content
       
} else if recordTranslations.Locale == "zh-HK" {
    someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID].Title.ZH_HK = recordTranslations.Title
        someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID].Content.ZH_HK = recordTranslations.Content

} else if recordTranslations.Locale == "zh-CN" {
          someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID].Title.ZH_CN = recordTranslations.Title
        someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID].Content.ZH_CN = recordTranslations.Content
}
}
```

Comment: someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID].Title.EN_US = recordTranslations.Title => it says "cannot assign to someMap[recordTranslations.SchoolGroupID].Title.EN_US (value of type string)", I tried to assign a string to it but it blamed me. What have I done wrong?